# Predicting customer behavior from previous transactions

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am working on a dataset where the customers previous transactions are to be used to predict the future transaction given the transaction history of every customer. The dataset does not come with the labels of the prediction and are to be created. Can you please suggest me the citeria's required to build the predictive labels from the values in the dataset. Given are

- **Customer**: Id, Age, Salary, Purchases, Returns, Area_of_residence, Language spoken
- **Transactions**: ID, Shop_Code, Transaction_type, City, Store Type, Purchase, Returns, Invoice, Units_sold
- **Shop**: ID, City_code, Total_revenue, Store_area, Store_launch_date

Answer (score 0):

Here is [link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/competitive-data-science-predict-future-sales/kernels) to the similar problem that you are dealing with, where practioners are using various strategy to solve this problem.

The basic idea is that you have history of all customer's transaction. Now use that history(let's suppose `7` days history) as input and predict the transaction for next day for that customers. More concretely, you can find in the link.